# multiple condition not correctly evaluated

Tags: c

Hi I'm new in this forum.
I have a problem with a function c that should verify the correctness of the structure of an isbn code so formatted "3 numbers one dash and ten numbers (ex: 111-1111111111).
The function should return 1 if the code is correct 0 otherwise, unfortunately it always returns 0 even if the code is correct.
I attach my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int checkIsbn(char isbn[]);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    char v[] = "111-1111111111";

    printf("%d",checkIsbn(v));


    return 0;
}

int checkIsbn(char isbn[]){

    int ret = 0;//return value

        //I check the individual characters
        if((isdigit(isbn[0]) != 0) && (isdigit(isbn[1]) != 0) && (isdigit(isbn[2]) != 0) &&
          (isbn[3] == '-') && (isdigit(isbn[3]) != 0) &&
          (isdigit(isbn[5]) != 0) && (isdigit(isbn[6]) != 0) && (isdigit(isbn[7]) != 0) &&
          (isdigit(isbn[8]) != 0)&& (isdigit(isbn[9]) != 0) && (isdigit(isbn[10]) != 0) &&
          (isdigit(isbn[11]) != 0) && (isdigit(isbn[12]) != 0) && (isdigit(isbn[13] != 0))){//the characters respect the structure

            ret = 1;

        }

    return ret;
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I think you'll find that `(isdigit(isbn[3]) != 0)` should be for the next character: `(isdigit(isbn[4]) != 0)`.

Comment: wow - that if-statement is just too complex - way too many hard coded numbers.

Comment: You also need to check there are no *more* than 14 characters.

Comment: That if-statement is way too complex. Keep things more simple. Perhaps like:

    if (isdigit(isbn[0]) == 0) return 0;
    if (isdigit(isbn[1]) == 0) return 0;
    ....
    return 1;

Much easier to understand.

Comment: Let me give you this advise: imagine you keep that function, and within a year or so you need that function again, so you need to read and understand it again. Will you be able to do so? Most probably not, therefore try for find a way (using newlines, loops, comments, ...) so make this function more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` expression, you're using element `3` twice:

```
(isbn[3] == '-') && (isdigit(isbn[3]) != 0)
```

Change your expression to:

```
if((isdigit(isbn[0]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[1]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[2]) != 0) &&
   (isbn[3] == '-') && 
   (isdigit(isbn[4]) != 0) &&
   (isdigit(isbn[5]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[6]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[7]) != 0) &&
   (isdigit(isbn[8]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[9]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[10]) != 0) &&
   (isdigit(isbn[11]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[12]) != 0) && 
   (isdigit(isbn[13] != 0))
```

As an alternative, you can use a `for` loop:

```
// ISBN Has The Form: "NNN-NNNNNNNNNN"
int checkIsbn(char isbn[])
{
    // Error Check
    if((strlen(isbn) != 14) || (isbn[3] != '-'))
        return 0; // Fail

    for(i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        if((i != 3) && (isdigit(isbn[i]) == 0))
            return 0; // Fail
    }

    return 1; // Pass
}
```

Yet another alternative is to use pattern matching to verify the ISBN string.

```
int checkIsbn(char isbn[])
{
    char *pattern = "NNN-NNNNNNNNNN";
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        if (pattern[i] == '\0')           // at the end of the pattern
            return (isbn[i] == '\0');     // return 1 if we're at the end of the isbn
        else if (pattern[i] == 'N' && !isdigit(isbn[i]))  // should be a digit
            return 0;                                     // return 0 if not a digit
        else if (isbn[i] != pattern[i])   // should be the given character
            return 0;                     // return 0 if character doesn't match
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216182/discussion-on-answer-by-fiddling-bits-multiple-condition-not-correctly-evaluated).

Comment: thank you very much